# Use create-react-app behind corporate firewall

Tags: node.js, reactjs

there is any way for work with `create-react-app` behind corporate firewall by setting a proxy.

i have setted the proxy on npm and yarn, but this is what i see when try to `create-react-app my-app`:

```
Creating a new React app in F:\react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

You appear to be offline.
Falling back to the local Yarn cache.

yarn add v0.23.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find any versions for "react" that matches "latest" in our cache. Possible versions: ""
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact --offline react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app / from F:\react
Done.
```

Comment: To future readers: Recent versions of `create-react-app` have gotten a lot smarter about detecting proxies etc. Make sure you're running the latest version and try again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Looks like this bug has [now been fixed](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/3320), and should no longer be present in [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md#110-january-15-2018).

---

This problem is caused by the fact that the yarn registry is hard-coded in react-scripts to `registry.yarnpkg.com`: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/createReactApp.js#L692

As per [this pull request](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/2884), if the yarn registry is not reachable, then [it will check](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/createReactApp.js#L696) to see if you have the `https_proxy` environment variable set, and then if so it will verify that *that* server is reachable, instead of the hard-coded yarn registry.

To reiterate, it's not enough to set the proxy/https-proxy configs in npm/yarn - you also need to set the `https_proxy` environment variable, because that's what create-react-app will check when determining if you are online. For example:

```
https_proxy=https://my.corporate.proxy create-react-app my-new-project
```

Answer (score 26):

I had been struggling with this for weeks. What worked for me was to include --use-npm at the end of the command and finally I got rid of the "no lockfile found" error. I sincerely hope this helps someone else struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Hi Erik, --use-npm works perfectly, thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: Thank you Erik !

Comment: `--use-npm` worked for me as well, with `strict-ssl=false`, `always-auth=true`, `_auth` and `ca`.

Comment: Works perfect thanks. My corporate proxy is a bit annoying so this fix is easy and effective.

Answer (score 9):

I have had this issue as well, and I solved this with this command:

```
create-react-app hello-world --use-npm --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, try first running `yarn add react react-dom react-scripts` in an empty folder.  This will add the required packages to yarn's local cache.  You can then delete that folder and run `create-react-app my-app` again and it will hopefully work.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem - [See details](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4953)
`npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"`

Comment: This really is the best answer. Thanks from Syria.

Answer (score 1):

These settings solved it for me:

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```