# Not able to create react app using "create-react-app demo" in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm trying to create a react app using global installed command "create-react-app" and getting the error as listed below:

I've fired the commands:

`1:sudo npm install -g create-react-app`

`2:create-react-app demo`

> yarn add v1.9.4
>   (node:10344) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
>   info No lockfile found.
>
> [1/4] Resolving packages...
>   error Couldn't find any versions for "react" that matches "latest" in our cache (possible versions are ""). This is usually caused by a missing entry in the lockfile, running Yarn without the --offline flag may help fix this issue.
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Just for your information:

npm version is **5.6.0**
node version is **v10.1.0**

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105317/use-create-react-app-behind-corporate-firewall

Comment: Thanks @ArpitSrivastava It really works!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.