# Create-React-App (CRA) getting stuck while Creating a new React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I tried to run `npx create-react-app testreact` and it gets stuck on

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\surik\desktop\testreact.
```

No errors are thrown, just stuck endlessly on this

I would like to tell you that I am behind a proxy of my college but I have added it to npm config and npm install works seemlessly.
I am new to this so I am not able to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: You using node command prompt or normal cmd command? also try creating app in different drive than C. let me know

Comment: have you tried a diff project name?

Comment: try help from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105317/use-create-react-app-behind-corporate-firewall